# Different filesizes for images generated using octave and python

Tags: python, matlab, ffmpeg, octave, scikit-image

I am using python (scikit-image) and octave to generate 200 images as follows

**Python3**

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imsave

images = [255*np.ones((100,100), dtype=np.uint8),  # white
             np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.uint8)]  # black

for i in range(200): # save alternating black and white images
    imsave('%04d.png'%(i+1), images[i%2])
```

**Octave**

```matlab
pkg load image;

im1 = 255*ones(100,100); # white
im2 = zeros(100,100);    # black
for i=1:200
    name = sprintf('%04d.png', i);
    if mod(i,2) == 0
        imwrite(im1, name);
    else
        imwrite(im2, name);
    end
end
```

Next, I use ffmpeg to generate two videos (alternating white and black frames) from these two sets of images using the following command

```sh
ffmpeg -r 10 -loglevel quiet \
       -i ./%04d.png -c:v libx264 \
       -preset ultrafast -crf 0 ./out.mkv
```

1. Sizes of image files generated by both these codes are different.

- Octave {white: 192 bytes, black: 98 bytes}
- Python {white: 120 bytes, black: 90 bytes}

2. Sizes of video files generated from these octave and python images are significantly different from each other.

- Octave {filesize: 60 kilobytes}
- Python {filesize: 116 kilobytes}

**Why do we have this apparently very strange behavior?**

**EDIT**

Since it was suggested that the behavior might be due to octave and python using different bit-depths to store the images, I changed the octave code to use 8 bit numbers

```matlab
im1 = uint8(255*ones(100,100)); # white
im2 = uint8(zeros(100,100));    # black
```

and now the image file sizes are nearly the same

- Octave {white: 118 bytes, black: 90 bytes}
- Python {white: 120 bytes, black: 90 bytes}

but the problem is still the same for video files, octave: 60K, python: 116K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scikit-image (using PIL underneath the hood) saves the PNGs in 8-bit format, while octave uses 16-bit (as mentioned by @carandraug below, this happens because floating point data is provided in Octave, which PNG does not support directly, so the data is converted to uint16 instead).  This alone would explain the difference in sizes (although their may be other subtle differences in the ways their encoders work).

scikit-image:

```
$ identify 000*.png
0001.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 120B 0.000u 0:00.000
0002.png[1] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 90B 0.000u 0:00.000
0003.png[2] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 120B 0.000u 0:00.000
0004.png[3] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 90B 0.000u 0:00.000
0005.png[4] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 120B 0.000u 0:00.000
0006.png[5] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 90B 0.000u 0:00.000
0007.png[6] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 120B 0.000u 0:00.000
0008.png[7] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 90B 0.000u 0:00.000
0009.png[8] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit RGB 256c 120B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Octave:

```
$ identify 000*.png
0001.png PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 98B 0.000u 0:00.000
0002.png[1] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 192B 0.000u 0:00.000
0003.png[2] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 98B 0.000u 0:00.000
0004.png[3] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 192B 0.000u 0:00.000
0005.png[4] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 98B 0.000u 0:00.000
0006.png[5] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 192B 0.000u 0:00.000
0007.png[6] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 98B 0.000u 0:00.000
0008.png[7] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 192B 0.000u 0:00.000
0009.png[8] PNG 100x100 100x100+0+0 16-bit RGB 98B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

On my machine (ffmpeg 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), both videos end up being 116KB.

Comment: Can you please provide some details about your system and the ffmpeg version you are using?

Comment: "while octave uses 16-bit." is not that simple. In the OP question, he never converts the data to uint8 like he does in the python code. Because of that, the data is of class double but because the png format is requested (which does not support floating point pixel values), it's converted to 16 bit (and I believe this is dependent on graphicsmagick build options).